# How to catch anything between //BEGIN and //END blocks?

Tags: php, regex

```
//BEGIN domain
//data for domain
'domain'=>array(

 'site'=>'4',
 'domain'=>'test.dev',
 'locale'=>'en_US',
 'site'=>'2',
 'domain'=>'anothertest.dev',
 'locale'=>'de_DE',
 'site'=>'3',
 'domain'=>'localhost',
 'locale'=>'nl_NL',
),
//END domain
```

How can I catch anything between the //BEGIN and //END blocks. And preg_replace it. I tried using

```
'/\/\/BEGIN (.*) \/\/END/'
```

But the new lines are troublesome.

Comment: Can regex catch comments..?

Comment: Try escaping the slashes: `'/\/\/BEGIN (.*) \/\/END/'`.

Comment: I am sorry I am not sure what you mean by that @PRPGFerret

Comment: @Itay I did escape it like '/\/\/BEGIN (.*) \/\/END/'  but it seems not to show in the code above. I try editing it.

Comment: @Minahalmon: as an aside comment, when you write a regex that contains literal slashes, change the pattern delimiter to `~` or `#`, then you don't need to escape all slashes. But in your case, Kolink way is better than using a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newlines are not a problem. Just use the `s` modifier.

That said, you can do better:

```
$start = strpos($input,"//BEGIN");
$start_nextline = strpos($input,"\n",$start)+1;
$end = strpos($input,"//END");
$result = substr($input,$start_nextline,$end);
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. I have to edit it abit but it finds all the content between the BEGIN and END tags.